# Sum of columns of a row from a list (without 'sum' function)

Tags: python

So I have this function here:

```
def row_sums(square):
    """Returns a list of the row sums in a magic square"""
    numbers = []
    for row in square:
        result = 0
        for col in row:
            result += col
        numbers.append(result)
    return numbers
```

Which when a magic square like the following is entered, it will return the sum of the rows without using the in-built function "sum":

```
square = [
   [1, 2, 3, 4],
   [5, 6, 7, 8],
   [9, 10, 11, 12],
   [13, 14, 15, 16]
]
print(row_sums(square))
```

And so this will return:

```
[10, 26, 42, 58]
```

So this one good, but for the next question in my lab quiz. It is asking me to modify the function so that it will print the sum of the columns. So for example entering the same:

```
square = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16]
]
print(column_sums(square))
```

Will return

```
[28, 32, 36, 40]
```

Having trouble figuring this out. Will be great if someones has some time to help me out! (Note: the purpose of the function is not to use the "sum" function which is unusual but it is for nested loop practise)
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to do the required OP ..

```
sum_of_columns = [sum([row[i] for row in square]) for i in range(0,len(square[0]))]
```

Without built in sum function :

```
def array_sum(a):
  result=0
  for i in a:
     result+=i
  return result

sum_of_columns = [array_sum([row[i] for row in square]) for i in range(0,len(square[0]))]
```

According to OP condition function to do column_sum :

```
def column_sums(square):
   """Returns a list of the columns sums in a magic square"""
   numbers = []
   for i in range(0, len(square[0])):
       result = 0
       for row in square:
           result += row[i]
       numbers.append(result)
   return numbers
```

Comment: Isn't that using the in-built 'sum' function though? Its for a lab quiz at Uni where they want us to make the function without using the sum function. Cheers

Comment: ohh  ... then you can write your own sum function , just replace it with built in one .. ...

Comment: Would you be able to put that in a similar format with my function style? Its  a bit confusing to me. Sorry

Comment: Just how two 'for' statements are in the same line? could you just show me by changing my first function? so I can tell where the changes were needed

Comment: @ReiYoshinari you can test it .